# Why do I get a "Malformed data passed to binarizer" while using jsQR even when I am, as the documentation is dictating, passing a Uint8ClampedArray?

Tags: javascript, image, types, qr-code, getimagedata

I have the code below to send an external image to jsQR. When running this, I get `Error: Malformed data passed to binarizer.`

However, when I check the type of `imageData` (using the Chrome dev tools) it is, as expected, a `Uint8ClampedArray`.

Hope someone can help!

```
    const width = 400;
    const height = 400;

    const blue = document.createElement("img");
    blue.src = "https://i.ibb.co/d4hsDfQ/blue.jpg";
    blue.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "");

    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    if (context) {
        blue.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(blue, 0, 0, width, height);
            const pixels = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            const imageData = pixels.data;
            console.log(imageData);
            const code = jsQR(imageData, blue.width, blue.height);

            if (code) {
                console.log("Found QR code", code);
            }
        };
    }
```

See also: [jsQR](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR#readme)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error... I should use

```
const code = jsQR(imageData, width, height);
```

instead of:

```
const code = jsQR(imageData, blue.width, blue.height);
```